# Xamarin Forms with Google Play Services

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created a XamarinForms app with latest version of XamarinForms stable v2.3.3.180 from NuGet in Visual Studio 2015.

Next, In NuGet manager I try to add latest stable version of Google Play Services Location https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 
which currently is 42.1001.0.

But Google Play Services says it needs XamarinForms 2.3.3.193:

[image]

After hitting OK, the project explorer shows several references with yellow icons, and compiler gives warnings it couldn't find references:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it is? And when you press OK it will be upgraded automatically. So what seems to be your problem?

Comment: I hit OK but Visual Studio shows a lot of yellow warning icons near references and give warnings that it couldn't load them

Comment: Open nuget manage check the xamarin.forms version

Comment: @MikeMa and how does this help? I have latest Xamarin Forms stable version 2.3.3.180

Comment: Which package exactly are you installing?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms 23.3.180 has a dependency on the Android Support Library version 23.3.0.  You have version 25.1.0 installed which isn't supported by Xamarin Forms.

Drop back your Android Support Library to version 23.3.0 and the issue should go away.

Comment: Thanks. What are the changes in the latest Xamarin Goole Play Services? Do you know or can I read it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't make sense. You're saying " You have version 25.1.0 installed which isn't supported by Xamarin Forms.".
Version 25 is what Xamarin Google Play Services requires, and I need latest version of Xamarin Google Play Services.
What is the solution?

Comment: I am trying to install Xamarin Google Play Services Location https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location/42.1001.0 I am updating the question to be more clear

Comment: @JamesL Sorry, I missed part of the point in your question but my advice still stands. I think you need to remove all of your packages there and re-add them starting with Xamarin.Forms as it has a specific requirement on the Android Support Library that your package manager seems to want to update to a later, unsupported version. Do you still see this behaviour when you do this, and _then_ add the Google Play Services package?